# How to customize the header display color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery mobile. I was trying to change the default header color to a #013A6F.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
  <h1> Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Any insight??

Comment: How did you try to change it? What happened? Are you satisfied?

Comment: I was looking into jQuery theme. I was wondering wheter in should overwrite in jQuery's theme css or should I overwrite in my style sheet??

Comment: It should be in the css folder...at least thats where the 'default' colors are for regular jQuery themeroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this would be your css.[[Link here]](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.css)
If so, do this.

```
.ui-bar-b h1{
    background-color: #013A6F;
}
```

Comment: should I make the changes to jquery.mobile.theme.css??

Comment: @peterpan: i would suggest you add a new css called `theme-addon.css`. better for maintaining things easily. otherwise you will forget what all did you change after a while :)

Comment: @peterpan why did u put `hi` after `.ui-bar-b` ?

Comment: @SudheerKumar: its `h1` actually :)

Answer (score 5):

You can actually easily add your own themes.

This: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/themes/valencia/jquery.mobile.theme.css if a second set of themes from the project repository.  To make add your own, you can title them anything you wish, provided you wish to title them a single letter a-z.

For instance, if you wanted to add your own theme 'x', it would look something like:

```
.ui-bar-x { .... }
```

The file linked about is an excellent example at what you have to play with.  And, as naveen pointed out, it is the .ui-bar-? class you'd want to play with to change the header color.

There are a few third-party themes linked here, sadly a few of the links seem broken - they looked pretty nice when I originally saw it: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/custom-theme-28-2-2011

Answer (score 1):

This is a class in jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css,
here I have used the web gradient colors as #a2cbe7 & #6aaedb. You can replace them with your  own color codes.

```
.ui-bar-b{border:1px solid #456f9a;background:#6aaedb;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:0 -1px 1px #254f7a;background: #6aaedb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6aaedb 0%, #a1cae6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6aaedb), color-stop(100%,#a1cae6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6aaedb 0%,#a1cae6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6aaedb 0%,#a1cae6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6aaedb 0%,#a1cae6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6aaedb 0%,#a1cae6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6aaedb', endColorstr='#a1cae6',GradientType=0 );}
```